# How to make my radio, checkbox and text area inputs responsive?

Tags: html, css

Below code was done in Codepen.  Here is link: https://codepen.io/andyzam/pen/mdVvrLB

When I resize the window, the items in the table resize properly.  But the radio buttons, checkboxes, and text area inputs stay fixed.  How do I get those to move?

Do I need to add something to the #radio, #checkboxes, and #textarea IDs?  I tried using # radio label {} and using different display properties but they still remained stationary.

```
body{
  background: lightblue;
  font-family: monospace;
  margin: 0px;
}

p {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 14px;
}

#title {
  text-align: center;
}

#description {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 500px;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: justify;
    padding: 10px;
}

input {
  width: 250px;
}

label {
  font-size: 14px;
  margin-right: 0px;
}

table {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: 35em;
}

td {
  text-align: right;
  width: 250px;
  padding: 10px;
}

input:invalid {
  border: 2px dashed red;
}

input:invalid:required {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, pink, white);
}

input:valid {
  border: 2px solid black;
}

select {
  width: 260px;
}

select:invalid:required {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, pink, white);
}

select:valid {
  border: 2px solid black;
}

#radio {
  display: block;
  margin-left: 53em;
  padding: 10px;
}


input[type="radio"] {
    width: 20px;
}

#checkboxes {
  display: block;
  margin-left: 53em;
  padding: 10px;
}

input[type="checkbox"] {
    width: 20px;
}

#text-field {
  display: block;
  margin-left: 45em;
  padding: 10px;
}

#submit-button {
text-align: center;
  padding: 20px;
}


<html>
  <body>
    <title>TikTok User Survey</title>
    <main>
      <h1 id="title">TikTok User Survey</h1>
      <p id="description">We are gathering information from various TikTok users to gauge their satisfaction with the social media platform.</p>
      <p> All fields are required.</p>
      <form id="survey-form">
        <table>
          <tr>
          <td><label for="name" id="name-label">Your name:</label></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="name" name="name-label" placeholder="Your Name" required></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td> <label for="email" id="email-label">Enter your email:</label></td>
            <td><input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" required></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td> <label for="number" id="number-label">How many followers:</label></td>
            <td><input type="number" id="number" name="number" placeholder="No. of Followers (0-100k)" required min="0" max="100000"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <label for="age">How old are you?:</label></td>
            <td>
  <select id="dropdown" name="age" required>
    <option disabled selected value> -- select an option -- </option>
    <option value="under13">Under 13</option>
    <option value="13-20">13-20</option>
    <option value="20-30">20-30</option>
    <option value="over30">Over 30</option>
  </select>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
        <p>My gender:</p>
        <div id='radio'>
          <input type="radio" id="male" name="gender" value="male">
            <label for="male">Male</label><br>
<input type="radio" id="female" name="gender" value="female">
  <label for="female">Female</label><br>
<input type="radio" id="other" name="gender" value="other">
  <label for="other">Other</label>
        </div>
        <p>Favorite types of videos:</p>
        <div id="checkboxes">
          <input type="checkbox" id="dancing" name="dancing" value="dancing">
<label for="dancing">Dancing</label><br>
<input type="checkbox" id="cooking" name="cooking" value="cooking">
<label for="cooking">Cooking</label><br>
<input type="checkbox" id="pranks" name="pranks" value="pranks">
<label for="pranks">Pranks</label><br>
        </div>
        <p>Any additional comments about what you like:</p>
        <div id="text-field">
          <textarea name="message" rows="10" cols="30">I also like....</textarea>
        </div>
        <div id="submit-button">
        <button type="submit" id="submit">Submit</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </main>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried using `flexbox`? https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that you set a fixed margin-left on your radio buttons.

```
#radio {
  display: block;
  margin-left: 53em;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

If you want to center your items perhaps you should do like you do with the description and use auto:

```
#description {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 500px;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: justify;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

However an even better way might be to give a [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex) value to the containing element and then you can center elements from there if that is how you wish to position them.

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Flexbox isnt defined by horizontal or vertical centering since you can change the direction of centering. But in a default case `justify-content: center;` will center horizontally and `align-items: center;` will center vertically.

Outside of this i would also sugest you style using classes instead of ids. Classes can be repeated in more than one place and that is something you will appreciate when styling something like a checkbox that is likely to exist at several places.

Comment: Flexbox is a great idea.  Is there a way to align these vertically?  I used `flex-direction: column;` but then the radio buttons are atop the labels.  Would I have to style the input and the labels individually?  Here is what I have now: https://codepen.io/andyzam/pen/mdVvrLB

Comment: @Andy i would create a div to contain label and input and then have a different styling inside of the div.